# we done the changes in production mode and now we are trying to make it live but facing issue "theme css,js not loading"

Tags: magento2

we done the changes in production mode and now we are trying to make it live but facing issue "theme css,js not loading".

require js error after deploying.

we have tired with some commands but not getting final solution.

Comment: have you done compile ?

Comment: Have you tried with removing generated/code and generated/metadata folders?

Comment: Can you run this query into DB "UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 0 where path = 'dev/static/sign';" I hope It's working

Comment: @AnasMansuri yes i have done all magento commands with remove generated metadata